# Jmeter Groovy global variable behaviour

Tags: groovy, jmeter, global-variables

I have written a script in Jmeter as below:

```
vars.put("status","0");
if(vars.get("status") == "1"){
    __setProperty(totalAmount, ""+ (Integer.parseInt(${__property(totalAmount)}) + 150))};
}
else{    
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("incorrect status");
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}
```

totalAmount is global variable. Even though status is set to 0 it is incrementing the total amount by 150.
What could be the issue? Please help. I am new to Jmeter & Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) directly inside Groovy script as:

   - they conflict with [Groovy GString Templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html)
   - they conflict with Groovy compilation caching feature
   - they may resolve into something which will cause compilation failure

   so update your code to look like:

   ```
   vars.put("status","0");
   if(vars.get("status") == "1"){
      props.put(totalAmount, (props.get('totalAmount') as int) + 150)
   }
   else{    
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("incorrect status");
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
   }
   ```
2. JMeter properties are **global** for the whole JVM so if you have **ever** set the property - it will have the value until you update it or restart JMeter. So if you want to start "clean" you need to set the property value to zero like:

   ```
   props.put('totalAmount', '0')
   ```

   or remove it completely like:

   ```
   props.remove('totalAmount')
   ```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter.